# Rxjs perform switchmap multiple times for an array behaviour

Tags: angular, rxjs

Basically what i want to do is for example get all the authors of books and then get all the books for each author. I couldn't find an operator for this.

code for better explanation:

```
this.actividadService.getActividades()
.switchMap((result) => {
  const actividadUno = result[0];
  console.log(result);

  if (actividadUno) {
    for(let actividad of result){
      console.log('actividad = ');
      console.log(actividad);
      return this.actividadFechasFinalService.getActividadByIDYear(actividad.ID, actividad.Anio).catch(this.handleError);
    }
  } else {
    return Observable.of('No results');
  }

},
(actividades, actividadesFechas)=>[actividades, actividadesFechas])
.subscribe(actividades => this.arregloActividadesFlatMap = actividades);
```

The problem with this is that switchmap only returns for the first item on the array

This is what my service returns:

```
getActividades(): Observable<ActividadPlaneacion[]>{
   return this.actividadesSubject.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) method. First build out an array of all your observables then call them with forkJoin.

```
.switchMap((result) => {
    // make array of observables
    let books = result.map(actividad => this.actividadFechasFinalService.getActividadByIDYear(actividad.ID, actividad.Anio).catch(this.handleError));

    return Observable.forkJoin(...books);
});
```

This will call all the observables in parallel

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the right answer but because of my reputation it doesn't upvote.

Comment: @DaríoVillalta no worries, glad i could help!